# Glassfish V3 custom log location and system properties

Tags: java, logging, glassfish

In my company we are currently upgrading to GF V3 from V2. We have around 20 domains and we keep the logs outside the domain logs folder.

In GF V2, I set this by changing every log related entry in domain.xml to:
`/logs/glassfish/${com.sun.aas.domainName}/server.log`

I did that on every domain domain.xml and GF resolved that to the corresponding domain name. This no longer works on GF 3. I changed it first on domain.xml but I saw that the logging.properties file was overriding that so I changed the line *com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.file* value for the one I mentioned I used on GF 2 but the domainName system property does not get resolved, it's just treated literally, so I end up with a *com.sun.aas.domainName* folder inside my logs folder.

So my question is how can I get this system property resolved? The documentation says I still can use it. Does it have to do with the fact that the logging.properties file is not XML? Is there a way I can bypass the logging.properties file to see if the variable would get resolved from the settings in the domain.xml file?